# How I can cast the GroupedEnumerable to IEnumerable<T>

Tags: linq, ienumerable

I have an expression tree project which works well apart from when I use the GroupBy statement. For statements such as “Where” and “OrderBy” the following line returns a “System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable”

```
var result = theQueryableSource.Provider.Execute(newExp);
```

The following line then works correctly as expected.

```
var test = ((IEnumerable<T>) result).GetEnumerator();
```

If I use the “GroupBy” statement, the first line of code returns a “System.Linq.GroupedEnumerable”. When the second line runs I get an exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.GroupedEnumerable`3    [EntityItemInterfaceClassLib. ReaderEntityItem,System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],     EntityItemInterfaceClassLib. ReaderEntityItem]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[EntityItemInterfaceClassLib. ReaderEntityItem]'.

Can anyone advise on how I can cast the GroupedEnumerable to  IEnumerable, or explain what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What do you expect the `T` to be in your `IEnumerable<T>`?

`GroupedEnumerable<TSource, TKey, TElement>` implements `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>>` already. In this case, you would be trying to cast the`IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>>` back to (presumably) an `IEnumerable<TSource>`.

`GroupedEnumerable<TSource, TKey, TElement, TResult>` implements `IEnumerable<TResult>` already. In this case, you would be trying to cast an `IEnumerable<TResult>` back to (presumably) an `IEnumerable<TSource>`.